# "Usernoted" process eating all my cpu

Tags: performance, activity-monitor, virus, processor

What is this process and how can I get rid of it? I ran antivirus etc but without any success. Terminating it in the activity monitor won't change anything.

[image]
[image]

```
Sampling process 416 for 3 seconds with 1 millisecond of run time between samples
Sampling completed, processing symbols...
Analysis of sampling usernoted (pid 416) every 1 millisecond
Process:         usernoted [416]
Path:            /usr/sbin/usernoted
Load Address:    0x10ef1f000
Identifier:      usernoted
Version:         845.40.3
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2020-11-02 14:29:16.852 +0100
Launch Time:     2020-11-02 14:24:15.500 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Physical footprint:         11.4M
Physical footprint (peak):  11.7M
----

Call graph:
    2702 Thread_4148   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2702 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff6eaa8cc9]
    +   2702 ???  (in usernoted)  load address 0x10ef1f000 + 0x2cd5  [0x10ef21cd5]
    +     2702 autoreleasepool<A>(invoking:)  (in libswiftObjectiveC.dylib) + 46  [0x7fff6e75cd8e]
    +       2702 ???  (in usernoted)  load address 0x10ef1f000 + 0x3cce  [0x10ef22cce]
    +         2702 CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 40  [0x7fff34c58489]
    +           2702 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 462  [0x7fff34bcfe3e]
    +             2702 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1319  [0x7fff34bd09c2]
    +               2702 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 247  [0x7fff34bd1ef5]
    +                 2702 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 60  [0x7fff6ebea170]
    +                   2702 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff6ebe9dfa]
    2702 Thread_4198   DispatchQueue_20: usernoted_server  (serial)
    + 2592 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 15  [0x7fff6eca8b77]
    + ! 2592 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 290  [0x7fff6eca9a3d]
    + !   2592 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 596  [0x7fff6ea5ec09]
    + !     2592 _dispatch_lane_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 363  [0x7fff6ea555d6]
    + !       2571 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 597  [0x7fff6ea54c44]
    + !       : 2571 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff6ea4f658]
    + !       :   2542 _dispatch_call_block_and_release  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 12  [0x7fff6ea4e6c4]
    + !       :   | 2534 ???  (in usernoted)  load address 0x10ef1f000 + 0x3829  [0x10ef22829]
    + !       :   | + 2532 ???  (in usernoted)  load address 0x10ef1f000 + 0xf6c5a  [0x10f015c5a]
    + !       :   | + ! 1427 ???  (in usernoted)  load address 0x10ef1f000 + 
Sample analysis of process 416 written to file /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Have a look at the load graph at the bottom of the Activity Monitor window, the system load actually is quite low. There are probably 3 (or 7) additional cores on your CPU basically doing nothing right now.

Comment: well my fans are going crazy @nohillside

Comment: You can try `pkill -STOP -l usernoted` to pause the process and see whether the fan slows down again.

Comment: `cd `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`
rm -rf com.apple.notificationcenter
killall usernoted; killall NotificationCenter`